# MySQL data to objective-c object

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios, database

I'm wondering how to take data from a remote MySQL database and parse it into an objective-c object. For example, if I have a list of food in my database, and each food item has certain properties, like a name, price, description, how would I parse each item in the database to a food object class in objective c.

I usually parse XML which iterates over each food item, so that I can do things like food.description to get the food's description...

Currently I can acquire my data using php and storing it in JSON. I the use the JSONtouch library to parse it. How could I use a similar structure but taking the data above and translating it into an object?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a database you intend to run locally on the iOS device, or a db which is accessed through a web service, etc.? Please add more detail about your intended setup.

Comment: Remote database through web service. Question is edited thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GNUstep's GDL2 library, to see whether it will work for you (and whether the license is acceptable). It's an ORM library that supports MySQL among other data sources.

Otherwise, you could wrap the MySQL client library in an NSIncrementalStore subclass to use it via Core Data.

Comment: Does it make sense to go to all that trouble rather than just storing all the information in an NSDictoomary or something. Isn't the benefit of an object supposed to be for convenience when accessing data? In any case thanks for you advice.

Comment: Your question was about creating objects of a particular class, not dictionaries; I answered that. Convenience may be a benefit of OOP, but sometimes you have to spend a little to save a lot. ORMs handle all the details of interacting with the DB, something NSDictionary does not do. They also encapsulate this work, so you never need to remember about it elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Can GNUstep's GDL2 library be used for apps that intend to be published? Because on the website it says that the library is currently being beta tested...

Comment: As I said, you need to discover whether it works for your case.